select one option then click save button and then it needs to appear in the screen
I'm working on the project, I need to learn how to works with outlined textfield, my problem is I have dropdown menu and it has options and I need choose one option then there is a save button in the below then I click that button, after that my option should appear in the screen as outlined textfield, that is the part I cannot do that in kotlin jetpack compose desktop. Please show me example how to do it, don't just answer it if possible, show me with examples, thank you in advance
